# Get a package directory path using importlig.resources with >=py37 compatibility?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a `constants.py` file which can be accessed to get global available paths through the whole package. I'm using `importlib.resources` which should be in standard lib since `python3.7` according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html.

This works but for some reason only on `python3.9` there's no support for directory resources with `resurces.path`.

```
E   IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '.../my_package/data'
```

This is the source code inside `constants.py`.

```py
from importlib import resources
from contextlib import ExitStack

# Access package data
file_manager = ExitStack()
MODELS_PATH = file_manager.enter_context(resources.path("my_package", "data"))
CONFIGURATOR_DATA_PATH = file_manager.enter_context(
    resources.path("my_package.configurator", "data")
)
```

Is there a way to achieve this with `>=py37` compatibility? Or maybe even a different approach since I'm not **100%** sure this is the best practice in general.

Comment: That output looks like it came from a pytest. Can you show us the test?

Comment: I can't show much sadly but basically in my tests I just imported the file `constants.py` like `import my_package.constants as C` and that's it. The issue is most probably related to https://bugs.python.org/issue44162 . This is odd tho because in python3.10 the support is active again for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment the closest solution I could get was to check on the system version at runtime:

```py
import importlib.resources as resources

if sys.version_info >= (3, 9):
    MODELS_PATH = str(resources.files("my_package").joinpath("data"))
    CONFIGURATOR_DATA_PATH = str(
        resources.files("my_package.configurator").joinpath("data")
    )
else:
    from contextlib import ExitStack

    file_manager = ExitStack()
    MODELS_PATH = file_manager.enter_context(
        resources.path("my_package", "data")
    )
    CONFIGURATOR_DATA_PATH = file_manager.enter_context(
        resources.path("my_package.configurator", "data")
    )
```